# gnu screen and split regions

Tags: gnu-screen

I just figured out that it was possible to have split terminals with gnu screen.  But the problem is that it doesn't split windows, but create a new region which is always present.
 I'd like to be able to switch from a split window to another non-split window...

For example:

- in window 0 I'd like to run gdb split with minicom
- in another (window 1) I just would like to have a terminal
- in another (window 2) another instance of gdb split with another instance of minicom.

I can get this behaviour when calling screen inside screen!

But I'd like to know if it is possible to do that in a single session of screen. Because the ^a a escape thing really bothers me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at tmux: http://tmux.sourceforge.net/
I know it's not screen, but I believe it has the particular feature you are looking for.

Comment: Great ! this is exactly what I needed !
thanks a lot !